# configurable products are not showing up in the front end (catalog and search pages)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, configurable-product

My configurable products are not being shown on the front end. On the backend, Magento seems to list the configurable products as 0 inventory (although there is no input box for quantity amount for a configurable product).

1. all of their products are set to "in stock" and have quantities above zero
2. the configurable products themselves are also set to "in stock" [there is no setting for quantity - as mentioned above]
3. data is re-indexed and caches have been flushed
4. Using Magento 1.7.0.2
5. Using the popular extension Simple Configurable Products [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html)

please advise...

Comment: Are they enabled? Also, for each configurable option you need a single parent product that has all of the children associated with it. See the [magento admin demo](http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/index.php/admin/) and how they do it. Here is the [frontend demo](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/) for reference

Comment: yes, they are all enabled. Also, each configurable product has its associated products connected with it.

Comment: Check your theme files for errors. Try switching back to the default magento theme. If they show up there, then your issue is in your theme. If they do not show up there, start disabling the output of modules such as Simple Configurable Products. If that doesn't work, then reload the core of magento via ftp/ssh/scp. Lastly, if that doesn't work [check and repair your database](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool)

Comment: ok... tried it all and nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 12):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

the problem is with the code used in Simple Configurable Products (OrganicInternet)

I would like to note that I was having two seperate issues at once - the above, and the product price index refused to be indexed (I was recieving this message: *Cannot intialize the indexer process*, which was explained as *SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*)

as it turned out both problems were related, and below solved them both ;)

1. in the file  **/ app / code / community / OrganicInternet / SimpleConfigurableProducts / Catalog / Model / Resource / Eav / Mysql4 / Product / Indexer / Price / Configurable.php**

change:

```
$select->columns(array(
        'entity_id'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('e.entity_id'),
        'customer_group_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.customer_group_id'),
        'website_id'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('cw.website_id'),
        'tax_class_id'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tax_class_id'),
        'orig_price'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.price'),
        'price'             => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
        'min_price'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
        'max_price'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
        'tier_price'        => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price'),
        'base_tier'         => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price'),
    ));
```

to:

```
$select->columns(array(
        'entity_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('e.entity_id'),
        'customer_group_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.customer_group_id'),
        'website_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('cw.website_id'),
        'tax_class_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tax_class_id'),
        'orig_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.price'),
        'price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
        'min_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
        'max_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.final_price'),
        'tier_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price'),
        'base_tier' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.tier_price'),
        'group_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.group_price'),
        'base_group_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.group_price'),
    ));
```

and

```
$outerSelect->columns(array(
        'customer_group_id',
        'website_id',
        'tax_class_id',
        'orig_price',
        'price',
        'min_price',
        'max_price'     => new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(inner.max_price)'),
        'tier_price',
        'base_tier',
        #'child_entity_id'
    ));
```

to

```
$outerSelect->columns(array(
        'customer_group_id',
        'website_id',
        'tax_class_id',
        'orig_price',
        'price',
        'min_price',
        'max_price'     => new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(inner.max_price)'),
        'tier_price',
        'base_tier',
    'group_price',
    'base_group_price',
        #'child_entity_id'
    ));
```

source: [main issue](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/pull/85) together with [this](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/commit/6d88e5e) (however please note that the correct code is **'base_group_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.group_price'),** and not **'base_group_price'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('pi.*base_*group_price'),**

2. also, in the file: **/ app / code / community / OrganicInternet / SimpleConfigurableProducts / Catalog / Model / Resource / Eav / Mysql4 / Product / Indexer / Price.php**

change

```
$this->cloneIndexTable(true);
```

to

```
$this->clearTemporaryIndexTable();
```

source: [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/286645/)

It took me several hours to figure this out so I wrote this post to help anyone else from wasting all that time.

best of luck!